# How to concatenate cells based on a multiple search in Google SpreadSheets

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a series of columns like this:

```
Project1   Project2
--------   -------- 
Bob        Mark
Clara      Boris
Mark
```

In another sheet I'd like to have the list of names and the projects they're participating. Like this:

```
Bob     Project1
Clara   Project1
Mark    Project1, Project2
```

The problem is that it seems that I need to do multiple matches and retrieve the first cell of the column if the match give positive results.

I think I need to use ArrayFormula with Match, but i'm unable to find this out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a formula which could help you with this. it basically has **ifs** Formula which check multiple if conditions and reflects the output of the condition which matches the first.

it checks if the value is in both columns and if this is not true then it checks for each column respectively.
    =IFS(AND(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A$2:A,0))),NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!B$2:B,0)))),"Project1,Project 2",NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A$2:A,0))),"Project1",NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!B$2:B,0))),"Project2")

Here, 'Sheet2' has same data as given in your question. Sheet 3 looks like this.

[image]

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Part #1: get a unique list of items from multiple columns

`=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA('Sheet1'!A2:B&","),,2^99)),,2^99)," ,",1)))`

- change `'Sheet1'!A2:B` to your range

Part #2. Get the list of matches joined by ", "

`=TEXTJOIN(", " , 1, ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(FIND(Sheet1!$A$2:$B,A1)*(Sheet1!$A$2:$B<>""),0),"select sum(Col"&JOIN("), sum(Col",ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&COLUMNS(Sheet1!$A$2:$B))))&")"),2,),Sheet1!$1:$1,"")))`

- change `Sheet1!$A$2:$B`, `Sheet1!$1:$1` to your ranges
- change `A1` to a cell with name
- copy the formula down

---

- change `Sheet1!$A$2:$B` to `indirect("Sheet1!$A$2:$B")` and count range dynamically for a better use.